# LAN cable not working

Tags: lan

when I connect it does not work the internet connection by LAN cable. Even though there´s a slot for it. How can I make it work? or this LAN slot is not for connecting with cable the internet through the modem rooter.

Tablet Model: wwe10 Android version: 2.2V1.5:#3566 Kernel version: 2.6.32.9 infotm-sqa@infotm-sqa-desktop #72 Build number: FRF85B

Comment: make sure its not app related.  For example FolderSync app works fine with wifi but NOT over an ethernet cable, but at the same time chrome and other network features are working.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that your router is working and you can use WiFi, there could be two or more explanations to your problem:

1. Either your tablet and your router are not compatible with each other, the port might be there but might need a higher network adapter compared to the one in your WWE10 tablet.
2. There's a high possibility that your tablet network adapter is not working and that would mean you having it replaced.
3. WWE10 tablets are known to have an ethernet (LAN) adapter problem. What you could possibly do to remove this problem is have it flashed by an expert, or try doing it yourself using [this how to guide](http://www.androidtablets.net/threads/rom-guide-superpad-flytouch2-wwe10-android-2-2-v2-1-3925-usb-flashing.16530/).

Comment: As silly as it sounds, make sure the cable itself isn't damaged! Check if WiFi works as the answer above says, and make sure the ethernet cable works on something else (e.g. a PC).

Comment: That does not sound silly. It is even a good question.